# How to get meta_values using meta_keys using

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating custom CMS so i have one database table that should contain all of my website settings... example (metakey => sitelogo, sitename, email etc) and another column (metavalue => logo.png, Example Name, martin@asd.com etc).

I am done with one query to read the certain data from the database table, but i am not sure how to read all data with one query, or to update multiple data in one query.

**Corrected code:**

```
<?php
$stmt0 = $conn->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM settings WHERE meta_key IN ('site_name', 'login_logo', 'contact_email', 'instagram_token', 'instagram_photos', 'maintenance_mode', 'facebook_link', 'instagram_link', 'twitter_link', 'about_text', 'site_logo') ");
$stmt0->execute();
$stmt0->store_result();
$stmt0->bind_result($sitename, $login_logo, $email, $token, $photos, $maintenance, $facebook, $instagram, $twitter, $about, $sitelogo);
$stmt0->fetch();

echo $sitename;
?>
```

But now i have error_log... 
PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Could you please provide me some example PHP code how to proceed?

Comment: You may define all the metakey name in a single and get all the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read all data:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM settings
```

To read multiple values:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM settings WHERE meta_key IN (?,?,?...)
```

Where you have one `?` per value you're resolving, and an additional binding.

Note that PDO is a lot easier to work with when using variable queries like that, so if you're not too married to `mysqli` you may want to look at how PDO can help.

Comment: I have corrected my code, but now another problem... i have exactly 11 variables...

Comment: If you don't care about which variables, the first form will work. If you care about particular ones, use the second.

Comment: I need to echo that variables but why i got this error_log message? i have 11 variables in prepared query, also i bind 11 results...

Comment: If you run that query in a shell like `mysql` or MySQL Workbench you'll see you get one result *row* per entry, not one row with all entries. You're selecting one column, so you'll get one column per result. In the version I have here you get key/value pairs, so you'll need to bind two values. The reasonable thing to do at that point is populate an associative array with them.

Comment: Ohh yes, i got the point now! i have 11 rows not only 1... so i have loop through them in order to take all variables...